# What is __weakrefoffset__?

Tags: python, weak-references, datamodel

What is the `__weakrefoffset__` attribute for?  What does the integer value signify?

```
>>> int.__weakrefoffset__ 
0
>>> class A: 
...     pass 
... 
>>> A.__weakrefoffset__ 
24
>>> type.__weakrefoffset__ 
368
>>> class B: 
...     __slots__ = () 
...
>>> B.__weakrefoffset__
0
```

All types seem to have this attribute.  But there's no mention about that in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=__weakrefoffset__) nor in [PEP 205](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0205/).

Comment: See answer of user `user2357112` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011430/python-which-types-support-weak-references (in short: nonzero `__weakrefoffset__` means given type support weak references)

Comment: I saw that post already but it leaves a lot to be desired - doesn't explain what the value means, and doesn't provide any references for the claims.

Comment: `__weakrefoffset__` is completely undocumented, so it's hard to provide doc links. Literally the only place the string `__weakrefoffset__` shows up in the entire CPython repository is in the [PyMemberDef that defines it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L367).

Comment: Anyway, I've added some more explanation to my answer over on that question, plus a source link for `__weakrefoffset__` and a doc link for `tp_weaklistoffset`, because it's useful information to have there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CPython, the layout of a simple type like `float` is three fields: its type pointer, its reference count, and its value (here, a `double`).  For `list`, the value is three variables (the pointer to the separately-allocated array, its capacity, and the used size).  These types do not support attributes or weak references to save space.

If a Python class inherits from one of these, it’s critical that it be able to support attributes, and yet there is no fixed offset at which to place the `__dict__` pointer (without wasting memory by putting it at a large unused offset).  So the dictionary is stored wherever there is room, and its offset in bytes is [recorded in the type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591145/8586227).  For base classes where the size is variable (like `tuple`, which includes all its pointers directly), there is special support for storing the `__dict__` pointer past the end of the variable-size section (*e.g.*, `type("",(tuple,),{}).__dictoffset__` is -8).

The situation with weak references is [exactly analogous](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#weakref-support), except that there is no support for (subclasses of) variable-sized types.  A `__weakrefoffset__` of 0 (which is conveniently the default for C static variables) indicates no support, since of course the object’s type is known to always be at the beginning of its layout.

Comment: `tp_dictoffset` is also exposed to Python. It's `__dictoffset__`, just like `__weakrefoffset__`.

Comment: @user2357112: I thought there was, but was evidently too hasty when I went to confirm it.  Edited.

Comment: @wim: Yes, as provided by the C `offsetof` macro.

Answer (score 0):

It is referenced in [PEP 205](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0205/) here:

> Many built-in types will participate in the weak-reference management, and any extension type can elect to do so. **The type structure will contain an additional field which provides an offset into the instance structure which contains a list of weak reference structures.** If the value of the field is <= 0, the object does not participate. In this case, `weakref.ref()`, `<weakdict>.__setitem__()` and `.setdefault()`, and item assignment will raise `TypeError`. If the value of the field is > 0, a new weak reference can be generated and added to the list.

And you can see exactly how that works in the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/weakrefobject.c).

Check out the other answer for more why it exists.