# Why tuple inheritance generates zero weakrefoffset while list inheritance generates positive weakrefoffset?

Tags: python, tuples, weak-references

As known, we cannot create weakref to `__builtin__ object` in python.

```
import weakref
a = 1
awr = weakref.proxy(a)  # TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'int' object
a = (1, 2)
awr = weakref.proxy(a)  # TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'tuple' object
```

For that the field `__weakrefoffset__` refers to availability of weakref, we can see something below:

```py
class TupleInherit(tuple):
    pass


class ListInherit(list):
    pass


print 'TupleInherit.__weakrefoffset__', TupleInherit.__weakrefoffset__
print 'ListInherit.__weakrefoffset__', ListInherit.__weakrefoffset__
print 'tuple.__weakrefoffset__', tuple.__weakrefoffset__
print 'list.__weakrefoffset__', list.__weakrefoffset__
# OUTPUT:
# TupleInherit.__weakrefoffset__ 0
# ListInherit.__weakrefoffset__ 48
# tuple.__weakrefoffset__ 0
# list.__weakrefoffset__ 0
```

As above represented, `list`, `tuple` and `tuple` inheritor doesn't provide availability of weakref, while `list` inheritance provides. Result is shown below:

```
import weakref
a = TupleInherit()
awr = weakref.proxy(a)  # TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'TupleInherit' object

a = ListInherit()
awr = weakref.proxy(a)  # OK
```

So, why? May the reason be that tuple is built by `__new__`?
And what if we wanna create a tuple inheritor which support weakref?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60213903/14311263

Comment: oh, thks. So,  is that means there is no solution?

Comment: I couldn't find any (I ran into the problem with `namedtuple`, and in the end just used another structure)

Comment: Yeah, problems...